# How can I set $.ajaxStart() and $.ajaxStop() to fire only on POST requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'd like to set global handlers for ajax requests, but only for `POST` cases.

Unfortunately, global handlers `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxStop()` will fire for all requests and as far as I can see there is no parameter passed onto the handler function. The documentation is also scarce, as most jQuery documentation is.

Can I detect the request type from within a global ajax handler?

Comment: i don´t think so. although ajaxStop is called if EVERY ajax call has finished, therefore what should the request type be if there were more than one request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use these events instead:  [ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)   [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST") console.log('POST request');;
}).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST") console.log('POST request');
});
```

Using ajaxSend, you can still abort request using: `xhr.abort()`

***EDIT:***

Better would be to use [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) as in @DemoUser's answer

Comment: Thank you! 

Do I understand correctly that `$.ajaxStart()` is fired once for the entire queue, so it doesn't have a type itself, while `$.ajaxSend()` is fired for each request, so it can access the request type?

Answer (score 5):

i guess you could do something like this:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options) {
    if(options.type !== 'POST') {
        options.global = false;
    }
});
```

See:: [jQuery prefilters](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/)