# Modify data property for every ajax request and type POST using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call used in different situation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  type: "POST"
  data: {val: '1', test: 'test1' },
  ...
});
```

I want, for every ajax start and for "POST" method only, to add a parameter to `data` property.

I used this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    //if type is POST then
    // data.myProp = 1;  or similar
});
```

How to get `data` and `type` from ajaxStart ?

**EDIT**

If I use ajax.preFilter then will not work fine.

So:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' || options.type === 'POST') {
        options.data = $.extend(originalOptions.data, { myProp : 1});
    }

});
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    data: { myItem: 'tes' },
    ...
});
```

then `data` will not contain `myProp` because `$.ajax` declaration will override data over `data` from `ajax.preFilter`

I want to have both `myProp` and `myItem` parameters to be send to somewhere on server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980840/how-can-i-set-ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-to-fire-only-on-post-requests

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's ajaxSetup - I would like to add default data for GET requests only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996993/jquerys-ajaxsetup-i-would-like-to-add-default-data-for-get-requests-only)

Comment: It is no duplicate. I will explain above in my edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) :

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' || options.type === 'POST') {
        options.data = $.extend(originalOptions.data, { myProp : 1});
    }

});
```

Comment: See my updated post (question) to see why ajaxPreFilter is not working

Comment: @SnakeEyes try : `options.data.myProp = 1;`

Comment: @SnakeEyes I don't know why you say it doesn't work . I just made a test and it adds the right parameters (I did it with GET). [see here](http://i.imgur.com/6LflJOt.png)